# Swift and moving images

Tags: xcode, swift

Im new with Xcode and swift.

Im doing this game from this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLOhirsXx9c&list=PL1YTxp2xLtqSiBhoAiaImXFcjAAxvo1es&index=1 )

The game is working good, but i wanna do that game with pictures, not code.

I can add background but i can't get pictures top of the background and get them moving.

example : this is the code for the ground that its moving to the right, but i wanna put 2 images instead of code.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class KBMovingGround: SKSpriteNode {

  let NUMBER_OF_SEGMENTS = 20
  let COLOR_ONE = UIColor(red: 88.0/255.0, green: 148.0/255.0, blue: 87.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

  let COLOR_TWO = UIColor(red: 120.0/255.0, green: 195.0/255.0, blue: 118.0/225.0, alpha: 1.0)

init(size: CGSize) {    
    super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.brownColor(), size: CGSizeMake(size.width*2, size.height))

    anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)

    for var i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SEGMENTS; i++ {       
        var segmentColor: UIColor!

        if i % 2 == 0 {
            segmentColor = COLOR_ONE
        } else {  
            segmentColor = COLOR_TWO 
        }

        let segment = SKSpriteNode(color: segmentColor, size: CGSizeMake(self.size.width / CGFloat (NUMBER_OF_SEGMENTS), self.size.height))

        segment.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
        segment.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i)*segment.size.width, 0)

        addChild(segment)
    } 
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func start(){

    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-frame.size.width/2, y: 0, duration: 1.0)
    let resetPosition = SKAction.moveToX(0, duration: 0)
    let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, resetPosition])

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveSequence))
 }
}
```

And i wanna do same thing with that "ninja" moving top on the ground.

Then i wanna make the ground and the objective thats moving on it go for the same speed so how do i make that?

And how i can make it speeding up when the player gets further at the game.

Thank you for the help beforehand and sorry for my bad english!